# covert div to img with kendo ui

Tags: html, css, angular, kendo-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

Im trying to create image from div content, by using kendo.drawing.drawDOM.
When I run it all elements in my div confusined,
Here is my html code using bootsrap:

```
<div id="mytryapp" name="mytryapp" data-ng-init="init()" class="buttonprint content-wrapper ">
    <style>
        * {
            font-family: "Open Sans Hebrew", Alef !important;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="clearfix">
        <div ng-show="userNum!=null" class="inputfieldwrapper buttonprint right col-sm-6  col-sm-push-6   horizontalinputfieldwrapper ">
            <label id="userNumLbl" for="disForUserNum" class="font-bold col-lg-4 col-lg-push-7 col-md-10 col-md-push-2 col-xs-push-8" ng-bind="'מספר משלם:'"></label>
            <div class="inputContainer col-lg-7 col-lg-pull-4 col-sm-7 col-sm-pull-5 col-xs-pull-0 col-xs-pull-1 col-xs-3">
                <label ng-model="userNum" class="col-lg-6 col-lg-push-5 col-md-5 col-md-push-7 col-xs-push-8 ng-binding ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-bind="userNum"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="inputfieldwrapper buttonprint right col-sm-6   col-sm-pull-6    horizontalinputfieldwrapper">
            <label id="userNumTax" class="font-bold col-sm-4 col-sm-push-8 col-xs-push-8" for="disForUserNumTax" ng-bind="'מספר נכס:'" ></label>
            <div class="inputContainer col-lg-7 col-lg-pull-4 col-sm-7 col-sm-pull-5  col-xs-pull-0 col-xs-pull-1 col-xs-3">
                <label ng-model="userNumTax" class="col-lg-6 col-lg-push-7 col-md-5 col-md-push-7 col-xs-push-8" ng-bind="userNumTax"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="inputfieldwrapper buttonprint right col-sm-6  col-sm-push-6   horizontalinputfieldwrapper ">
            <label id="userEmail" for="disForUserEmail" class="font-bold col-lg-4 col-lg-push-7 col-md-10 col-md-push-2 col-xs-push-8" ng-bind="'דואר אלקטרוני:'"></label>
            <div class="inputContainer col-lg-7 col-lg-pull-4 col-sm-7 col-sm-pull-5 col-xs-pull-0 col-xs-pull-1 col-xs-3">
                <label ng-model="userEmail" class="col-lg-6 col-lg-push-5 col-md-5 col-md-push-7 col-xs-push-8" ng-bind="userEmail"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div  class="inputfieldwrapper buttonprint right col-sm-6   col-sm-pull-6    horizontalinputfieldwrapper">
            <label id="cellUserlbl" for="cellUsertxt" class="font-bold col-sm-4 col-sm-push-8 col-xs-push-8" ng-bind="'טלפון נייד:'"></label>
            <div class="inputContainer col-lg-7 col-lg-pull-4 col-sm-7 col-sm-pull-5  col-xs-pull-0 col-xs-pull-1 col-xs-3" >
                <label class="col-lg-6 col-lg-push-7 col-md-5 col-md-push-7 col-xs-push-8 " ng-model="tel" ng-bind="lDetailsUser[2].data" ></label>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the display in browser:
[image]

This is the image:
[image]

Someone have any idea how can I resolve this issue?
Maybe the kendo doesn't support bootstrap calsses?

Thank you a lot!!!